# Cucumber this.Before() hook not executing (Yeoman ember generator)

Tags: ember.js, cucumber, ember-testing

in my test/features/support/world.js

```
module.exports =  function(){
 var PersistenceWorld = function PersistenceWorld(callback){
  this.cleanUp(callback);
 };
 PersistenceWorld.prototype.addNewReciepe = function(callback){
 };
 PersistenceWorld.prototype.cleanUp = function(callback){   
 };
};
```

and My test/features/step_definitions/first_steps

```
module.exports = function(){
this.World = require('../support/world');
console.log(this);

this.Before(function (callback) {
 console.log("hey I run before each scenario");
 callback();
});

this.After(function (callback) {
 console.log("hey I run after each scenario");
 callback();
});

this.Given(/^user is on homepage$/, function(callback) {
  callback.pending();
}); 
};
```

when I donot require the world before after is getting fired.

- MyApp
- .sass-cache
- .tmp
- app

  1. bower_components

     - ember-mocha-adapter
- node_modules
- test
- features               **//I added this folder for cucumberjs features.**

  1. step_definitions   **//I added**
- lib

  1. mocha
  2. chai.js
  3. expect.js
- spec

Comment: How is cucumber invoked? Also, what do you mean by "when I do not require the world..."? Do you mean omitting the `-r` CLI option or avoiding Node's `require()`?

Comment: @jbpros thanks it was nodes require() now hooks are working. But it little confusing to setup cucumberjs with yeoman generator-ember , or plain ember-app-kit for beginner like me.Thinking of sticking to default test framework that comes with ember appkit for now. I like cucumber will get back to setting up cucumberjs later (I like cucumber)

Comment: thanks for the feedback. Could you elaborate a bit as to what isn't straightforward in the context of ember? We'd like to make things easier on the different usual stacks people are working on.